# How to prevent cloud build from running builds in parallel?

Tags: google-cloud-build

We are using cloud build for continuous deployment on GCP. When pushing commits to fast (e.g. on development) the triggered builds are running in parallel. Sometimes those interfere which one another. For example when two app engine deployments are running at the same time.

Is there a way or best practise to force builds which are triggered from the same build trigger to run one after another?

Regards,
Carsten

Comment: I'm wondering about the same thing. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 17):

I've done this by adding an initial step on my `cloudbuild.yaml` file. What it does is:

- Gets all the ongoing build id via `gcloud builds list --ongoing --format='value(id)' --filter="substitutions.TRIGGER_NAME=$TRIGGER_NAME"`.
- Loop through it but skip the first one, the list is sorted by latest created time so it won't stop the latest build which is the first index
- Run `gcloud builds cancel ${on_going_build[i]}` to cancel the build

Please see the `cloudbuild.yaml` below

```yaml
steps:
  - id: "Stop Other Ongoing Build"
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
    - -c
    - |
      on_going_build=($(gcloud builds list --ongoing --format='value(id)' --filter="substitutions.TRIGGER_NAME=$TRIGGER_NAME" | xargs))
      for (( i=0; i<${#on_going_build[@]}; i++ )); do
        if [ "$i" -gt "0" ]; then # skip current
          echo "Cancelling build ${on_going_build[i]}"

          gcloud builds cancel ${on_going_build[i]}
        fi
      done
```

Comment: Yeah that's not ideal though because sometimes you want the builds to be QUEUED not cancelled :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't by setup. But you can define custom builder. Create one which check if a build is running for your project with you repository. If yes, return an error code and crash the build process, else, continue the processing.

Comment: this is not a solution... I don't think that GCP has a solution either

Comment: You can also limit the number of Cloud Build in parallel in the same project. But it's applied for all build, not only for certain branch or repo.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how do you limit the number of Cloud Builds in parallel in a project?

Comment: You can go to the quotas and, find the Cloud Build concurrent build line and edit the quotas. You can set between 0 and 10. If you need more, ask your Google Cloud contact. I don't know if it's possible or not to do more (hard or soft limit)

Answer (score -1):

I've achieved sequential builds by using Logging Router + Pub/Sub triggers.

My first build is triggered by a commit and builds an image.
I inspected the logs and found that we have a single message like `textPayload="Pushing gcr.io/my-project/my-repo/my_image:latest"` when the build is finished.

By using the above as a filter this can then be routed to a Pub/Sub topic which triggers my second build that is using the image from the first one.

Might not work for all use cases since you need to find a single event emitted that signifies a successful build, but it definitely works when building images with the above.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the problem of making things sequential?
If you push 2 commits at around the same time, won't you build the image twice, and have 2x "Pushing ..." log messages, which then result in 2 new builds?